# REST GET API DB Marketplace

Tags: r, json, rest, get, httr

I would like to use the Germany Rail (Deutsche Bahn) API and I am struggling translating the working example into R.

For instance I can get data for all stations similar to a name:
[https://developers.deutschebahn.com/db-api-marketplace/apis/product/fahrplan/api/9213#/Fahrplan_101/operation/%2Flocation%2F{name}/get](https://developers.deutschebahn.com/db-api-marketplace/apis/product/fahrplan/api/9213#/Fahrplan_101/operation/%2Flocation%2F%7Bname%7D/get)

I managed to register an APP etc., so that I can try the following get results with success.

```
GET https://apis.deutschebahn.com/db-api-marketplace/apis/fahrplan/v1/location/Berlin
Header:
Accept: application/json
DB-Client-Id: myid
DB-Api-Key: mykey
```

Now im am struggling to translate this into the `GET` command of the `httr` package
I am open to other solutions

I figured that I only need the first part for the url

```
url<-"https://apis.deutschebahn.com/db-api-marketplace/apis/fahrplan/v1/location/Berlin"
```

I found this link with explanations to add headers and other stuff
https://httr.r-lib.org/reference/content_type.html

However, I am still struggling and not sure where I should go from something like this

```
r<-GET(url, add_headers(DB-Client-Id = client_id, `DB-Api-Key` = api_key)
       accept_json())
```

I cannot manage to replicate the header, in particular for the `add_headers`. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, it looks like you're going to want to hard code the `Accept:` header in the `add_headers()` argument like so.

```r
library(httr)
r<-GET(url, 
       add_headers(Accept="application/json",
                   `DB-Client-Id` = "client_id", 
                   `DB-Api-Key` = "api_key"))
```

For this should match the headers you need for your API request.

```r
add_headers(Accept="application/json",
            `DB-Client-Id` = "client_id", 
            `DB-Api-Key` = "api_key")

#Output
<request>
Headers:
* Accept: application/json
* DB-Client-Id: client_id
* DB-Api-Key: api_key
```

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: This works. I jus have a proxy problem on my other computer that I need to fix. thx for your help